# detecting flares with persistent homology

Tags: metric-spaces, homology-cohomology, topological-data-analysis

Can persistent homology detect "flares"

[image]

how does it do so, if it can.

I know persistent homology can certainly find "loopy" structure, like noisy circles, but I'm not sure about "flares".

Comment: Consider the following point clouds:A: 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 1,3 2,3 3,3 0,4 0,5 0,6 and B: 0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 0,4 0,5 0,6 0,7 0,8 0,9 0,10 notice that their Vietoris-Rips persistence barcodes are identical however A has 3 flares and B has 2 flares..

Answer (score 3):

Gunnar Carlsson likes to talk about using Borel-Moore homology to count the number of flares. See for example slides 108-110 at
[http://math.stanford.edu/~gunnar/math149intro.pdf](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Egunnar/math149intro.pdf).

Roughly speaking, in Borel-Moore homology you identify the "ends" of a space, and then consider the relative homology of the space modulo its "ends". So for a contractible space, the number of flares will be one more than the rank of the 1-dimensional Borel-Moore homology group. In a data analysis context, one could hope to identify the "ends" by using a measure of eccentricity.

Comment: That said, perhaps a more traditional way to detect flares in a data set using topological data analysis is to use Mapper (instead of persistent homology) with density or eccentricity as a filtering function. You then get a graph representation of your dataset that has been simplified but that still preserves the flares.